# Manga where a group of people get transported to a dungeon

Tags: story-identification, manga

So, from what I remember, a group of people get transported to a dungeon and to a safe room. They split off into their own dungeons with their own challenges, and they meet together in that same room after they're done. I think they were moved to dungeons to train them for Earth's doom?

Comment: Was this manga mostly in black & white or full colour? Were the main characters originally from the 'real world' or a fantasy world? Did any of them have any distinctive powers or weapons? And did they fight any notable opponents or monsters? Also, do you recall what any of the main characters looked like?

Comment: I believe it was in black and white, though I'm not 100% sure. And the characters were from real world, except for the spectators. Spectators as in the people watching or supervise. I'm not sure if it counts as a power, but they were able to talk to other groups through a kind of a group chat. I don't remember monsters, BUT I do remember a part where the challenge was a avoiding traps with the main character. I don't remember what anyone looked like,,

Comment: Did the people know each other originally before being transported? Were they friends, acquaintances, or total strangers?

Comment: They were total strangers that were just put in a group together

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it! It's called ***[The Tutorial is too Hard](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=177212)***.

After sinkholes appear all over the world, the MC gets a screen pop-up (like the ones in games) asking if he wants to join the tutorial world, and he selects "yes", along with choosing the hardest mode there was; hell mode. From there, he gets transported into a strange giant room with people.

From MangaUpdates:

> Lee Hojae had given up his life as a pro gamer, until one day he received a mysterious message: “Congratulations! You’ve been invited to the Tutorial World.” Intrigued, he enters the game and confidently chooses “hell” difficulty, but soon learns that he is trapped there. With a mere 0.01% survival rate, Hojae must somehow overcome the game’s agonizing challenges to figure out the real reason he was invited. This tutorial may be tough, but its secrets are what’s truly hellacious.